# Collision detection between bricks and ball (working with an array of numbers)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to detect a collision between my ball and my bricks with an array made of numbers. It works but not completely.

If you look at my code, you see an array made of numbers from 0 to 5. 0 means that there is no brick detected and the rest is made of a color. The problem is that my function only detects a collision with the color 1 (black) but not the rest. What is the problem?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mijnCanvas");
var mijnObject = canvas.getContext("2d");

var afbeelding = new Image();
var balkX = (canvas.width/2)-50;
var balkY = canvas.height-40;

var balX = canvas.width/2;
var balY = canvas.height-50;
var radius = 8;
var balNaarX = 5;
var balNaarY = 5;

function makenBalkKort() {
    mijnObject.drawImage(afbeelding, balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
}
afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort.png";

function makenBal() {
    mijnObject.beginPath();
    var mijnBalGradient = mijnObject.createRadialGradient(balX, balY, 0, balX, balY, 6);
    mijnBalGradient.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
    mijnBalGradient.addColorStop(1, "#FFFFFF");
    mijnObject.fillStyle = mijnBalGradient;
    mijnObject.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    mijnObject.arc(balX, balY, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    mijnObject.fill();
    mijnObject.stroke();
    mijnObject.closePath();
}

function tekenenObjecten() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    makenBalkKort();
    makenBal();
    makenMuur();
    collisieMetStenenX();

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(balX+balNaarX < radius || balX+balNaarX > canvas.width-radius) {
            balNaarX = -balNaarX;
        }

        if(balY+balNaarY < radius) {
            balNaarY = -balNaarY;
        }

        if(balY+balNaarY > balkY-radius) {
            if(balX+balNaarX >= balkX && balX+balNaarX <= balkX+afbeelding.width) {
                balNaarY = -balNaarY;
            }
            else {
                alert("Game over");
                document.location.reload(); 
            }
        }
        balX += balNaarX;
        balY += balNaarY;
    }, 1000);
}
setInterval(tekenenObjecten, 20);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function LinksOfRechts() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var balkNaarX = 10;
    var code = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(code == 37) {
        if(balkX > 0) {
            balkX -= balkNaarX;
        }
    }
    else if(code == 39) {
        if(balkX < canvas.width-afbeelding.width) {
            balkX += balkNaarX;
        }
    }
    mijnObject.drawImage(afbeelding, balkX, balkY, afbeelding.width, afbeelding.height);
});

canvas.addEventListener("click", function balkLangMaken() {
    mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Lang.png";
    setTimeout(function() {
        mijnObject.clearRect(balkX, balkY, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        afbeelding.src = "Afbeeldingen/BrickSmasher_Balk_Kort.png";
    }, 3000);
});

var stenenPerRij = 27;                              
var steenHoogte = 20;
var steenBreedte = canvas.width/stenenPerRij;

var stenen = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,4,4,4,0,1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,4,4,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
    [1,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,4,4,4,0,1,0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
];

function makenMuur() {
    for(var i = 0; i < stenen.length; i = i+1) {
        for(var j = 0; j < stenen[i].length; j = j+1) {
            tekenenStenen(j,i,stenen[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

function tekenenStenen(x,y,stenen) {
    switch(stenen) {
        case 1:
            mijnObject.fillStyle = "#0d0d0d";
            break;
        case 2:
            mijnObject.fillStyle = "#333333";
            break;
        case 3:
            mijnObject.fillStyle = "#595959";
            break;
        case 4:
            mijnObject.fillStyle = "#808080";
            break;
        case 5:
            mijnObject.fillStyle = "#a6a6a6";
            break;
        default:
            mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, steenBreedte, steenHoogte);
            break;
    }
    if(stenen) {
        mijnObject.beginPath();
        mijnObject.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        mijnObject.rect(x*steenBreedte, y*steenHoogte, steenBreedte, steenHoogte);
        mijnObject.fill();
        mijnObject.stroke();
        mijnObject.closePath();
    }
}

function collisieMetStenenX() {
    for(var i = 0; i < stenen.length; i = i+1) {
        for(var j = 0; j < stenen[i].length; j = j+1) {
            if(stenen[i][j] == true) {
                var steenX = j*steenBreedte;
                var steenY = i*steenHoogte;
                if((balX+balNaarX > steenX && balX+balNaarX < steenX+steenBreedte)
                && (balY+balNaarY > steenY && balY+balNaarY < steenY+steenHoogte)) {
                    balNaarY = -balNaarY;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML-code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BrickSmasher</title>
<style>
    canvas {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block; 
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="mijnCanvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
    <script src="BrickSmasher.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
 if(stenen[i][j] == true) {
```

with:

```
 if(stenen[i][j] > 0) {
```

or simply:

```
 if(stenen[i][j]) {
```

The reason is that when you compare with `true`, JavaScript needs to do a conversion. As one side of the equation is numeric, the boolean expression on the other side is converted to the numeric equivalent of `true`, which is 1. That means there is no equality when `stenen[i][j]` is 2, 3, ...

The last alternative works, because there the conversion is in the opposite sense: an `if` condition needs to resolve to a boolean value. So the numerical value is converted to boolean. And there any non-zero value will convert to `true`.

Comment: You sir, are the best ;-) Thank you

Comment: @trincot Wist u dat ik Belg was omdat u "Graag gedaan" schrijft of was dat gewoon puur toeval?

Comment: @KevinN my guess is your variable/file naming was a hint :)

Comment: @CupawnTae, true, I didn't want to suggest that; I just referred to the actual positions in the actual code.

Comment: Your code is filled with Dutch variable names. Not hard to see :-)

Comment: @trincot True that, never thought of it. I still have one question. If I work with "if(stenen[i][j] > 0)" does the number 0 in the array counts even if there is no rectangle present?

Comment: @CupawnTae, I rephrased it just now. Thanks.